# Как отключить предупреждение о TLS в EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Использую .Net 7, EF 7.0.5.
Строка подключения:

```
"TestConnectionString": "Server=MAIN;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;App=Test;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;",
```

При запуске вижу такое сообщение: `Security Warning: The negotiated TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol and is supported for backward compatibility only. The recommended protocol version is TLS 1.2 and later.`
Моя попытка убрать это сообщение из консоли: `Encrypt=False;` +         `AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SuppressTLSWarning", true);` (взято [тут](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/pull/1457/files/f49bc26d76259fa45f7f45388525ecb1aa1c3f6b)) и результата никакого, сообщение так и осталось.
Как его можно убрать?

Comment: А сервер где расположен? Azure? На стороне сервера можно указать минимальную версию TLS. Версии Windows на клиенте и сервере какие? Отключать это предупреждение не нужно, нужно проблему исправить, TLS 1.0 - неприемлемо для безопасного подключения.

Comment: Сервер локальный (есть своя серверная). Сервер: Windows Server 2019, SQL Server: 2008, клиентская - Windows 10. Настройки TLS (минимальная версия) указываются в самой Windows Server или где-то в Sql Server?

Comment: На клиентской OS включены TLS 1.0, 1.2

Comment: тут  с картинками что и как делать: https://learn.mediasite.com/course/enabling-tls-1-2/lessons/sql-server-configuration/

Comment: Спасибо, если получится - сообщу)

Comment: TLS 1.2 включен на сервере, 1.0 выключен вообще. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: SQL Server: 2008 - не староват?

Comment: Староват, но обновлять не хотят :)

Comment: Ну пока подозрения на то что сам сервак имеет проблемы с TLS.